# Can we use Markov chain instead of Hidden Markov Model to classify sequential data?

Tags: classification, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, sequential-pattern-mining

I was searching for an algorithm that can classify sequential data into categories. 
Let's say sequence '000111' falls into category A, and '01010101' falls into category B.

A lot of materials dealing with similar problems use Hidden Markov Model to classify the sequences. I was wondering if it is possible to use Markov chain to solve this kind of classification problem since there is no unobserved(hidden) state: only a sequence of 0s and 1s which is observable. I was also wondering that if  it is possible to use Markov chain to classify sequential data, why is  there more literature where Hidden Markov Models rather than Markov chains  are used for sequential data classification.

Comment: If there's no hidden state then there's no point in hidden markov chain